# virtualbox full disk though enough free space

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, diskspace, vdi

Guest Ubuntu:

## df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              15G   14G  116M 100% /

disk analyzer:
14GB used 13.3 free 900MB
/ 100% 6,6GB

7 GB free space are missing

can someone help?

Comment: not really a programming question - more likely to get a response on superuser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i found out that the files were still lying in the other location of the root trash which has not been shown.

By removing them from there the space was given free.

Hope it helps if anyone encounters the same error.